# Why am i getting a null value on my alertDialog.setMessage()?

Tags: java, php, android, android-studio

I'm a complete beginner at doing android apps. I don't know the reason why my **alertDialog** box is always showing a *null* value. The code is for **log** in via checking data on my **database**. Would appreciate any help.

I've changed my MySql port from 3306 to 3307 because 3306 is blocked.

```js
public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    Context context;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    BackgroundWorker (Context ctx) {
        context = ctx;
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String type = params[0];
        String login_url = "http://192.168.254.106/login.php";
        if(type.equals("login")) {
            try {
                String user_name = params[1];
                String password = params[2];
                URL url = new URL(login_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("user_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_name,"UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                String result="";
                String line="";
                while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
                    result += line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return result;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Login Status");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        alertDialog.show();
    }

}
```

heres the login.php

```css
<?php
require "connection.php";
$user_name = $_POST["user_name"];
$user_pass = $_POST["password"];
$mysql_qry = "select * from account_profiles where userName like '$user_name' and passWord like '$user_pass';";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $mysql_qry);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
echo "Login Success";
}
else {
echo "Login Failed";
}
?>
```

Comment: 1. Edit your question to add the php code.
2. You're vulnerable to sql injection.
3. Please hash your passwords and don't save them as plaintext.

Answer (score 0):

Handle the instantiation of the `AlertDialog` in the classes constructor not in `onPreExecute` that doesnt make sense, and will fix your issue.

```
BackgroundWorker (Context context ) {
    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
}
```

Now you can remove the `Context` global variable also.

Comment: Appreciate the help but It still returns a null value.

Comment: The value of ```result``` withing this code ```while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
                    result += line;
                }``` is I think causing the problem. Is my syntax wrong?

Comment: You said, "null value on my alertDialog.setMessage()". Now you say that it is the result that is null. Your question is bad, no cash log.